# JS moving image across screen and loading another when at the end

Tags: javascript, image, animation, screen

I am moving a gif across the screen from left to right and back again. As I want to animate a running person, I need to change the picture always when it is at the end of the screen. Can anyone help me with this?

I am new to JS.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

function runningLeft() {
    $("#run").animate({left: "-=300"}, 1500, "swing", runningRight);
}

function runningRight() {
    $("#run").animate({left: "+=300"}, 1500, "swing", runningLeft);
}

runningRight();});
```

```css
#run {position:absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="run"><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/vMIQqpANOmAaQ/giphy.gif"/></div>
```

BR
Seb

Answer (score 1):

append and remove image as background property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var imageUrl1 = "image 1 URL";

var imageUrl2 = "Image 2 URL";

function runningLeft() {
$("#run").css("background","");
    $("#run").css("background",function(){
   return "url("+imageUrl1+") center top no-repeat";
});
    $("#run").animate({left: "-=300"}, 1500, "swing", runningRight);
}

function runningRight() {
$("#run").css("background","");
    $("#run").css("background",function(){
   return "url("+imageUrl2+") center top no-repeat";
});
    $("#run").animate({left: "+=300"}, 1500, "swing", runningLeft);
}

runningRight();
});
```

```css
#run {position:absolute;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="run"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I`ve put in some image URLs in your vars imageURL1 and 2 but I can`t see pictures then. Do I need to change something else?

Comment: Its working fine in my local environment. May be referring the external resources from different origin might give raise to "CORS". Test in your local pointing towards local resources. Also work around in height and width of div (#run) as well as body.

Comment: Now it is working! The problem was that I havent set height and width, so it was not visible.

Comment: glad to help. Dont forget to accept the answer if it helped